# Count rows in a dataframe where date is in the past 7 days

Tags: pandas

I have this dataframe with a "date" column in it. I want to count the rows where the date is in the past 7 days. What's the best way to do this? I feel like using an If and a counter isn't very pandas-esque.

Also, I'm importing the data from a SQL db. Should I just load it already filtered with a query? What's the most efficient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider your dataframe is something like that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2021-12-03', '2021-12-02', '2021-12-01', '2021-11-30'], 'data': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
   date           data
0  2021-12-03     1
1  2021-12-02     2
2  2021-12-01     3
3  2021-11-30     4
```

if you want to filter the data between dates 2021-11-30 and 2021-12-02, you can use the following command:

```
df_filtered = df.set_index('date').loc['2021-12-02':'2021-11-30'].reset_index()
   date           data
0  2021-12-02     2
1  2021-12-01     3
2  2021-11-30     4
```

In the first step, you set the date to the index and after that use `.loc` method to filter your desired dates. In the final step, you can count the number of rows by using the `len(df_filtered)`

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

1. First, calculate the interval datetimes: **today** and **past 7 days**.

```
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
past7 = today - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
```

2. Use them to filter your dataframe:

```py
df_filtered = df[(df['date'] >= past7) & (df['date'] <= today)]
```

3. Get the df_filtered length:

```
print(len(df_filtered))
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
len(df[df['date'] > datetime.date.today() - pd.to_timedelta("7day")])
```

Comment: this one throws can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date

Comment: @Backtr4ck try datetime.date.today() instead datetime.datetime.now(). Check the edited answer.